# Entity Framework 4.1 issues with saving relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

So I have a DB setup with the following tables (using EF 4.1...also db is the context which is declared in the class)

- `Proposals` (many to many with `RegionDetails` linked via `ProposalRegionDetails` table)
- `RegionDetails` 
  (many to many with `RegionDetailsAnalysis` linked via `RegionDetailsRegionDetailsAnalysis` table)
- `RegionDetailsAnalysis`

Everything works fine with my code to add proposals and regiondetails.  The problem is when I try to add `RegionDetailsAnalysis`.

```
public void AddBenefitAnalysis(Proposal proposal, RegionDetail regionDetail)
    {
        RegionDetailEntity rde = db.RegionDetailEntities.FirstOrDefault(rd => rd.Proposals.FirstOrDefault().ProposalId == proposal.Id 
            && rd.RegionDetailType == regionDetail.RegionDetailType);

         // attach the benefit analysis as well
        RegionDetailsAnalysisEntity rdae= new RegionDetailsAnalysisEntity 
        {
            AddedDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            LastModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        rde.RegionDetailsAnalyses.Add(rdae);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The code runs through debugger without any issues, but the save doesn't occur.  rde is retrieved properly.  I don't get anything in `RegionDetailsAnalysis` table.  Not sure what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Are you using data annotations or fluent API to create the m..n relationships? Can you post the code for the RegionDetails to RegionDetailsAnalysis relationship mapping?